# Domain renewed but not active yet

Tags: domain, domain-name-system

My domain was expired yesterday, I renewed it today, but same redirection (This domain is parked, pending renewal, or has expired. Please contact the domain provider with questions.) is active yet. What is the solution? How can I do from serverside or domain panel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wait for some time. The DNS refresh takes some time depending on TTL.

Comment: How can I do regards to this period be shorter? Can I change any parameters on server or ip records, for being faster refresh on DNS?

Comment: You might not be allowed to do so. And the other thing is that the NIC in your machine or your ISP that you are using might not be refering to the root DNS. The subordinate DNS servers are configured by respective owners which you can do no change to. This is a simple latency. This is why, renewing within time is very important if one wants to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This takes some time in most of the cases. This is because, when a domain expires, the registrar changes the DNS entry to redirect all traffic to the doamin expired page/url. The changed DNS entries are propagated to all lookup servers, including the one that your NIC looks up to. The propagation depends upon the TTL in the servers.

Once you renew the domain after expiry, they restore the DNS entry. But depending upon the TTL of the varios DNS servers, this get reflected in the different server. So this might take some time.

Just wait and watch.

Answer (score 0):

Most domain providers say that the domain will be active in about 24-48 hours, but in my experience it usually takes around 7-8 hours since you made your payment.

So just chill out and relax :D